# making loop script that needs to remove list elements as it goes thru

Tags: python

## Python problem

```
import fnmatch

list_1 = ['family', 'brother', 'snake', 'famfor']

list_2 = ['a', 'f', 'f', 'm', 'i', 'l', 'y']

match = fnmatch.filter(list_1, 'fa????')

print match
```

This would give me

```
>> ['family', 'famfor']
```

how can i only get family in this query?
by checking list_2 for valid letters.

Comment: The question is not clear to me. `fnmatch.filter(list_1, 'fa????')` will match any string in `list_1` of length 6 whose first two letters are 'fa'. What kind of further checks do you wish to perform using `list_2`? Please explain better this point.

Comment: this is kind of smaler version of what im trying to do. List_2 is the base of the word im trying to find. The word in list_1 has to only have the letters from list_2. So i have to exclude all words in list_1 that have letters thats not in list_2.

Answer (score 1):

You can first convert `list_2` to a set for efficient lookups, and then use a list comprehension with a condition as a filter:

```
set_2 = set(list_2)
[w for w in list_1 if all(c in set_2 for c in w)]
```

This returns:

```
['family']
```